# Displaying result set dynamically

Tags: java, jdbc

```
   String query="select dept_id,deptName from dept";
    PreparedStatement ps=cnn.prepareStatement(query);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();    
    while(rs.next()){           
    String st1 = rs.getString(1);
    String str2= rs.getString(2);
    }       
    ps.close();
```

I made one method for each insert, update, delete queries that could be used around the project. In the same way I am trying to develop one select method that could get any query and return the results. I tried ArrayList to retriew the record and now its working but displaying records here there not in a sequence. The code is as follow:
public ArrayList selectQuery(
                String columNames,String tableNames,
                String whereClause,String whereValues)throws Exception{

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> resultList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();        
    ArrayList<String> resultRecord = null;  

try{
    if ((cnn==null)||cnn.isClosed()){
    cnn=DB.getOracleConnection();
    }

    if(whereClause==null || whereClause.equals("")){
        whereClause="";
    }

    String query = "select "+columNames+" from "+tableNames+" "+whereClause;

            PreparedStatement ps=cnn.prepareStatement(query); 

            if(whereValues==null || whereValues.equals("")){
    //do nothing
    }
    else{
        int j=1;
        String[] words = whereValues.split (",");
        for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++){   
            words[i]=removeDot(whereValues);
            ps.setString(j, words[i]);
            j+=1;
        }
    }//whereValuesNullCheck

            rs=ps.executeQuery();     
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();     

            while(rs.next()){                           

        resultRecord= new ArrayList<String>(); 

                    for(int i=1;i<=rsmd.getColumnCount();i++){        
                    resultRecord .add(rs.getString(i));   
                    }        
                resultList.add(resultRecord); 
            }     
    ps.close();      

        } catch (Exception e) {   
System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.toString());
SendEmail.send(mail,"raakh5@gmail.com","Problem in ASC.DAOMethods.select()", "+e.printStackTrace()+"); 
        }     

return resultList;

}//methodClosed
```

and I am calling in the following method

```
public String viewPatients(ArrayList<ArrayList> result,String option)throws Exception{

PatientDAO pd = new PatientDAO();
DAOMethods dm = new DAOMethods();

String dataSet1="",dataSet2="",dataSet3="",records="",data="",country="",nationality="",source="",center="";

for(ArrayList record : result){

String patientId    =(String) record.get(0);
String rDate        =(String) record.get(1);
String title        =(String) record.get(2);
String firstName    =(String) record.get(3);
String lastName     =(String) record.get(4);
String country1     =(String) record.get(5);
String nationality1     =(String) record.get(6);
String source1      =(String) record.get(7);
String center1      =(String) record.get(8);

String title1 = cm.title(((String)title));
String name     = title1+" "+firstName+" "+lastName;

country         = c.displaySepecificCountry(((String)country1));
nationality         = c.displaySepecificCountry(((String)nationality1));
source          = cm.source(((String)source1));
String centerLocation   = pd.centerLocation(((String)center1));
center          = c.displaySepecificCountry(((String)centerLocation));
int age=9;

dataSet1+=
    "<tr "+cm.rowColor()+">"+
    "<td width=110  height=32 align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+
    rDate+"</a></td>"+

    "<td width=110  align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+
    "<font color=blue><b>"+patientId+"</b></font></a></td>";    

dataSet3+=
    "<td height=32 class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+
    name+"</a></td>"+

    "<td width=75 align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+"><font color=blue><b>"+
    age+"</b></font></a></td>"+

    "<td width=140 align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+country+"</a></td>"+

    "<td width=75  align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+nationality+"</a></td>"+    

    "<td width=75  align=center class=normalFont>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=5&patientId="+patientId+">"+source+"</td>"+

    "<td width=45>"+
    "<a href=/servlet/PatientManager?option=6&patientId="+patientId+">"+
    "<img src=/images/edit1.png border=0></a></td>"+
    "</tr>";
}
records=dataSet1+dataSet2+dataSet3;

return records;
}
```

Its working with the results fine but displaying records here there like on this link: http://www.onlinenics.com/images/error.jpg

Comment: Is there a reason you're starting at column 1 and not 0 in "    for(int k=1;k<=rsmd.getColumnCount();k++){"? If there is only one column (the 0th), nothing will get put into the results ArrayList, which would explain why it's empty.

Comment: @Zarkonnen I think you are wrong, because he does `<=` to test the exit of the `for` loop. The reason to do so is that `getString` from `Resultset` accepts `1` as first element and not `0`. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)

Comment: K=1; because rs.getString(k) can not be (0). The problem seems to with DAOMethod class test method.

Comment: @Raakh can you edit the question and add the full main code that calls the `test` method ?

Comment: I think the problem is with ArrayList mechanism. There are number of records and each record has its own number of columns that is the actual problem. how can we change it to double ArrayList? One list will store number of records and the other ArrayList will contain this record values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the comments above are correct in speculating that different result sets get different numbers of columns back, you have to be able to tell which columns have values. Use the names of the columns to get the values. Use an empty string where you have none.